# Syntax error in helm install --set image.repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I have a custom image of NewRelic which I am trying to install using helm chart.

Image Repository looks like below

[image]

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY                           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
minionupdate                         latest    ********   4 days ago     431MB
<none>                               <none>    ********   4 days ago     431MB
quay.io/newrelic/synthetics-minion   latest    ********   5 days ago     431MB
```

When I pass the repository path, the execution fails.

```
helm install 123 1/2 -n newrelic --set synthetics.privateLocationKey=**  --set image.repository=minionupdate
```

Error as below.

```
kubectl get pods -n newrelic
NAME                                 READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
cpm-ap-south-1-synthetics-minion-0   0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          37s

Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                   From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                  ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled               24m                   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned newrelic/cpm-ap-south-1-synthetics-minion-0 to **
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  24m                   attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "**"
  Normal   Pulling                 23m (x4 over 24m)     kubelet                  Pulling image "minionupdate:3.0.65"
  Warning  Failed                  23m (x4 over 24m)     kubelet                  Failed to pull image "minionupdate:3.0.65": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for minionupdate, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
  Warning  Failed                  23m (x4 over 24m)     kubelet                  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed                  22m (x6 over 24m)     kubelet                  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff                 4m25s (x84 over 24m)  kubelet                  Back-off pulling image "minionupdate:3.0.65"
```

Comment: can describe the pod and check the events?

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: It looks like you are referencing an image on dockerhub that doesn't exist. Image repos on dockerhub should contain a `/` unless they are a core library images (eg base ubuntu).

Comment: Can you check my syntax of helm install and the way i have specified the repository name

Comment: Its a custom image I am trying to use !

Comment: I think it should be `--set image.repository=quay.io/newrelic/synthetics-minion`, where `minionupdate` is local image that is not visible to the cluster, if you need to use this you need load that image in a cluster as `pre-exist` image or push it the private repository, then `--set image.repository=full-url-of-image`

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], especially including the `image:` line from the Helm chart's Deployment manifest?  The chart could be doing literally anything with that `--set` option.  Also, to double-check, have you pushed your image to the registry?

Comment: @Adiii I am trying to use the custom image and locally, I have bundled a zscaler cert into the official image. Cant I use "minionupdate" locally and start my CPM application using helm install?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have not pushed the image to registry. Was getting error. I am trying to use this locally as a custom image.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY                           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
minionupdate                         latest    ********   4 days ago     431MB
<none>                               <none>    ********   4 days ago     431MB
quay.io/newrelic/synthetics-minion   latest    ********   5 days ago     431MB
```

Is this on your local machine? If so, then your problem is that you have built `minionupdate` locally but have not pushed it to a repo that kubernetes is able to reach.

If you wanted to use docker hub for example, it should be `your-docker-hub-user-name/minionupdate` and then you would use that in your kubernetes deployment.

For example, I would use `blenderfox/minionupdate` if I was to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes this is on my local machine, I want to use from my local machine only as I am using a custom SSL bundled with the "quay.io/newrelic/synthetics-minion" image.

Comment: You've tagged this question with amazon-eks, but you can't be using EKS and your "local machine only"?

Comment: I am trying to install newrelic CPM using the command in OP. The issue I am stuck in is my organization uses a zscaler certificate to communicate outside. And so most URL's are unable to connect due to cert issue, from the pod. But on the kubectl server I can easily configure the certificate. I am trying to find a way to communicate from the pod/container using the cert. I have bundled the image with cert locally and trying to use the same.